# Error using fprintf

Tags: matlab

My code looks as so:

```
PosHotspot = dataset('file', 'PositiveHotspotpos.txt', 'Delimiter', '\t');
a = 2;
exon_end = PosHotspot.total_exon;
exonposition = PosHotspot.ExonPos;
Isoformnumber = PosHotspot.Isoform;

fileID = fopen('PosHotspot_results.txt', 'w')
for j = 1:660
    exon = exonposition(j:j);
    Isoform = Isoformnumber(j:j); 
    b = exon_end(j:j) - 1;
    rng(0, 'twister');
    r=randi([a b],1,1000);
    less = sum(exon>r);
    greater = sum(exon<r);
    equal = sum(exon==r);
    fprintf(fileID, '%s %4f %4f\n',Isoform,less,greater)
end
fclose(fileID)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> Error using fprintf
>       Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
>
> Error in PositiveHotspotttest (line 24)
>           fprintf(fileID, '%s %4f %4f\n',Isofrom,less,greater)

I'm certain that it has to do with writing my information from Isoforms to the file.

Here's an example of what my file looks like:

```
chrom   Gene    Isoform   exon_start ExonPos total_exon exonpos_exontotal
chr20   ADA     NM_000022   43255096    4         13    0.307692307692
chr9    ALDOB   NM_000035   104187734   7         10    0.7
chr5    ARSB    NM_000046   78077674    7          9    0.777777777778
chr5    ARSB    NM_000046   78135178    6          9    0.666666666667
chr5    ARSB    NM_000046   78181406    5          9    0.555555555556
```

I want to output the `Isoforms` to my new file as well as the greater than and less than values. Is there a way to do this?

It's probably pretty simple, but again I'm new to matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Isoform = Isoformnumber(j:j);
```

to the more natural:

```
Isoform = Isoformnumber{j};
```

Like this you'll retrieve the content of the cell no. `j`, instead of the whole cell.